# Intuitively, why does growth proportional to the population size not diverge but growth proportional to pairs diverges to infinity in finite time?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, intuition

It's interesting that growth which is proportional to the current population doesn't diverge to infinity, while growth that is proportional to higher powers of the current population.

That is, the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=kx$ is solved by $x(t)=x_0e^{kt}$, which does not diverge in finite time, while the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=kx^2$ is solved by $x(t)=-\frac{1}{t-C}$, which diverges?

However, is there an intuitive way to understand this?

---

Because of the way these differential equations are solved, for the former...

1. $$\frac{dx}{dt}=kx$$
   $$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{kx}$$
   $$dt=\frac{1}{kx}dx$$
   $$t-t_0=\int_{x_0}^{x}{\frac{1}{kx}dx}$$

...and for the latter...

2. $$\frac{dx}{dt}=kx^2$$
   $$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{kx^2}$$
   $$dt=\frac{1}{kx^2}dx$$
   $$t-t_0=\int_{x_0}^{x}{\frac{1}{kx^2}dx}$$

...an alternative but equivalent question would be if there is an intuitive way why the area under $\frac{1}{x^2}$ from some positive $x_0$ to $\infty$ is bounded while the area under $\frac{1}{x}$ from some positive $x_0$ to $\infty$ is also $\infty$? That is, with the former, it takes infinite time to reach infinite growth, while with the latter, infinite growth can be reached in finite time?

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, this is equivalent to asking why, for $x_0>0$, $\int_{x_0}^\infty x^{-s}dx$ is infinite for $s\le1$ but not $s>1$. By the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), this is equivalent to asking why $\zeta(s):=\sum_{n\ge1}n^{-s}$ has the same behaviour. Indeed, asking *that* question is equivalent to working with growth from a [difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Relationship_to_difference_equations_narrowly_defined) rather than a differential equation, and intuitively the two kinds of power law, one with $\dot{x}$ on the left and the other with $x_{t+1}-x_t$, should have analogous behaviour. (After all, the difference equation is roughly what you get by frequently but discretely observing the continuous behaviour.) In these related problems, the $s\le0$ behaviour is obvious, since there's an "infinite rectangle" lower bound, so let's take the low-$s$ case to be $0<s\le1$ hereafter.

Let's tweak everyone's favourite proof the harmonic series $\zeta(1)$ diverges to address your question. Since$$2^{-s}N^{1-s}\le\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}n^{-s}\le N^{1-s},$$doubling the number of terms in the partial sum of $\zeta(s)$ increases it by a value we've bounded below and above. Say we start with $N=1$ then keep doubling $N$. The case $s=1$ is of course famous: the bounds are $\tfrac12$ and $1$, so it's obvious the series diverges (logarithmically, in fact). In fact, if $s<1$ the increase grows with $N$, making the divergence even faster. But if $s>1$, $N^{1-s}$ is an exponentially decaying upper bound on the increases, so$$0\le\zeta(s)\le\sum_{\ell:=\ln N=0}^\infty 2^{-(1-s)\ell}=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}.$$